# Can width of a Gridview's column can be changed in percentage in codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` having 5 columns, and last column is visible to some members only.
I want that when the last column`gvMessageList.Columns[4]` is inivisible, its width in percentage should be given to first column`gvMessageList.Columns[0]`.

Please, let me know, how is it possible.

My `GridView` is as follow:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMessageList" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
    DataKeyNames="MESSAGE_ID" CellPadding="4" PageSize="51" EmptyDataText="No Records Found." OnSorting="gvMessageList_Sorting"
    OnPageIndexChanging="gvMessageList_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="gvMessageList_RowDataBound" GridLines="None"
    CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subject" HeaderStyle-Width="30%" SortExpression="MESSAGE_SUBJECT" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D9EDF7"
            HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#0088CC">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hlnkMessageSubject" runat="server" Text='<%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["MESSAGE_SUBJECT"] %>'
                    NavigateUrl='<%# ((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["MESSAGE_URL"] %>'>
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="From" HeaderStyle-Width="14%" SortExpression="MESSAGE_FROM" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D9EDF7"
            HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#0088CC">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hlinkUser" runat="server" Text='<%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["MESSAGE_FROM"] %>'
                    NavigateUrl='<%#((System.Data.DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["FROM_URL"] %>'>
                </asp:HyperLink>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CREATION_DATE" HeaderText="On" HeaderStyle-Width="15%" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D9EDF7" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#0088CC"
            SortExpression="CREATION_DATE" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="To" HeaderStyle-Width="21%" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D9EDF7" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#0088CC">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTo" runat="server">
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Broadcast" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" Visible="false" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D9EDF7" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#0088CC">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblBroadcast" runat="server">
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In C# Codebehind:

I want increased percentage of first column here:

```
gvMessageList.Columns[4].HeaderStyle.Dispose();
gvMessageList.Columns[4].Visible = false;
```

Is it possible by using `gvMessageList.Columns[0].HeaderStyle.Width = ??` or something like it.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: `HeaderStyle.Dispose`, what do you expect it to do? You don't need to call [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w(v=vs.110).aspx) yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give the width property a new unit type.  the first parameter is the width you want, and the second is what measurement to use.  In the sample below, I'm telling the column to be 50% of the table's width.

```
gvMessageList.Columns[4].HeaderStyle.Width = New Unit(50, UnitType.Percentage);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the width as follows

```
 GrdDynamic.Columns[4].ItemStyle.Width=Unit.Pixel(500);
 GrdDynamic.Columns[4].ItemStyle.Width=New Unit(50, UnitType.Percentage);
```